# PHP: Unicode accentuated char and diacritics

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, tinymce

In our website, some Mac users have troubles when they copy-paste text from PDF files into a TextArea (handled by TinyMCE). All accentuated char are corrupted, and became for example `e?` for a `é`, `i?` for a `î`, etc. I cannot reproduce this problem with a Windows computer.

When I wrote the content of the TextArea on a file (before inserting it in the database), I just discovered that the initial `é` is visually different that a traditionnal `é` (on Vim, see below).

[image: Visual example of the problem]

Indeed :

```
// the corrupted é - first line of the screenshot
echo bin2hex($char); // display 65cc81

// traditionnal é
echo bin2hex('é');   // display c3a9
```

After searching a lot, here I am :
It seems that Mac OS copies Unicode accentuated chars as a combination of two chars: in our example, **`e + ́`**. So far, I didn't find any solution to replace corrupted `é` with the real one, to avoid `e?` in the database.

And I'm a little desperate.

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process of [normalizing the representation to one form or the other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization) is called, well, normalization. In PHP there's the [`Normalizer` class](http://php.net/normalizer) for that, sending all input through it is a good idea:

```
$input = Normalizer::normalize($input);
```

You likely want to normalize to form C, Canonical Decomposition followed by Canonical Composition.

Should that class not be available on your system, there's the [Patchwork UTF-8 library](https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/Patchwork-UTF8).

Comment: It should be noted that there is no actual corruption. Decomposed characters are perfectly valid.

Comment: @Tino Indeed. It should be investigated why the database or some process leading up to it *is corrupting* the decomposed characters.

Comment: Okay, so I just install `intl`, and `Normalizer::normalize()` give me that : `Ã©`. But I add an `utf8_decode()` and it give me `é` !!
I'm excited, I'm gonna test again and I will tell you what.

Comment: Ok. When I wrote `utf8_decode(Normalizer::normalize($input);` in my file, I get the result I wanted. Regular `é`, etc. However, in my database it is still `e?`. I'm gonna check what @hakre said.

Comment: @Ash Don't randomly use `utf8_decode`, handle encodings properly instead. I'm sure the problem with the database is due to a similar such mistreatment of encodings. See http://kunststube.net/encoding and http://kunststube.net/frontback.

Comment: U were right. It works without the `utf8_decode();`, my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This is just additional to what @deceze already answered. There are multiple ways in Unicode to specify the same (in the sense of equivalence) character.

You have a common example here:

```
65cc81
```

That are two Unicode codepoints in Utf-8 encoding.  `65` is `e` *LATIN SMALL LETTER E* (U+0065) and `cc81` is `&#x301;` *COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT* (U+0301) (it can not be displayed alone by your browser, so I took the HTML entity).

In Unicode this is called a *Combining sequence*. For some reason however, your database does not support it. Probably because the encoding of the column is not UTF-8 or the database connection has troubles with it.

It is canonically equivalent to

```
c3a9
```

That is a single Unicode codepoint in Utf-8 encoding. `c3a9` is `é` *LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE* (U+00E9). Looks like your database has no problem to deal with it, probably because it is re-encoded to Latin-1 / ISO-8859-1 by the database connection successfully.

So two ways of handling the data come to mind. It is either a problem in the re-encoding of the data or a problem storing the data.

As long as you're interested in de-composition of the composed unicode codepoint sequences, you should take the normalizer outlined by in [Deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586187/367456).

You can also allow UTF-8 to be stored into the database and then you should not have a problem, too.

Additionally you should probably normalize anyway so that sorting and comparing data in the database or your program works better. As you can see, the binary sequences differ which can cause problems for everything that compare on the binary level.

And sure, you save some traffic :)

Comment: Thnak you for your answer. Very usefull presentation, I learn a lot thanks to you ! :)

Comment: That nice to read. Also I found this blog post which is interesting in my eyes: [Unicode Normalization](http://annevankesteren.nl/2009/02/unicode-normalization) - it has some more links, some still working if you want to dig even deeper for the unicode part.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just Poket-ed it, and I will read it later (on the subway :))

Answer (score 0):

There is a tinymce configuration parameter which lets you define a function to process the pasted contents before insertion in the editor: [paste_preprocessing](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste)

Using that function you can replace the specialchars with the desired form

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
            // Content string containing the HTML from the clipboard
            o.content = o.content.replace(/\u2020/, 'x'); // example
        },
        paste_postprocess : function(pl, o) {
            ...
        },
        ...
});
```

Comment: The desired form would be the *Singleton* instead of the *Combining sequence*. Do you have a javascript library at hand that deals with that?

Comment: yes, it is the tinymce API: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html. but the javascript character conversion needs to be defined by the site admin in the function paste_preprocess

Comment: Interesting, but what is the name of the Normalizer class? I could not find it.

Comment: Interesting, but what is the name of the Normalizer class? I could not find it. - However google showed this one quickly: [walling / unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm)