# é and é have different ASCII values

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii

I am converting special characters using *htmlentities*, but I have come across 2 different types of é

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo htmlentities("é")."\n";
echo htmlentities("é")."\n";
?>
```

Outputs:

```
é
&eacute;
```

I outputted the ASCII values using this

```
echo ord("é");
echo ord("é");
```

outputs

```
101
195
```

Is there a way to force htmlentities to convert the e to the usable character?

Comment: What is a usable character? Unicode has multiple ways of showing accented characters

Comment: What about a `str_replace("é", "é", $string);` on the input to make all the `é` the same?

Comment: if you look at the example, one of the characters outputs as &eacute - that is the usable one. The character that outputs 195 works in htmlentities, but the character that outputs as 101 doesn't

Comment: ... but (extended) ASCII 195 should be ├

Comment: Actual ASCII does not even contain the character `é`. 101 in ASCII is just `e` – and with anything > 127, we are not even actually talking about ASCII any more, but more likely one of the `ISO 8859-xy` encodings. What character encoding you are actually using (with this data, and with the page where you output it) is the kind of information you should add here first of all.

Comment: @BrettGregson I suspect there are other characters that might do this, so I'd prefer a more futureproof method

Comment: `ord` only looks at the first _byte_ of whatever input value you feed it. So if `ord("é")` gives you 101 as a result, then you most likely have an actual `e` that is _combined_ with the accent in some form of Unicode encoding.

Comment: _Because_ `ord` only looks at the first byte, you can use `ord("é"[1])` and `ord("é"[2])` to check what the second and third byte values are (if they exist, if this is actually encoded as three bytes.) That would probably give you `101 204 129` here, meaning this is the UTF-8 representation of the basic Latin character `e` (U+0065) followed by U+0301, COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

Comment: @04FS updated question to reflect encoding UTF-8

Comment: @04FS yep it outputs `101 204 129`

Comment: Can you explain what you actually need the `htmlentities` “version” of this data for to begin with? What _actual_ problem are you trying to solve here? That is still rather unclear. Anyway, you can “normalize” such different Unicode representations of a character, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13586187/10955263 for basic info on that.

Comment: I would like both versions of the é character to output as `&eacute;`
I will look at normalize function

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 different UTF-8 strings here.

```
<?php
var_dump("é" === "e\u{301}");
var_dump("é" === "\u{e9}");
//bool(true) bool(true)
```

Try self: https://3v4l.org/QnHvg

The first string contain 2 characters, ASCII "e" and the unicode [U+0301](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/301/index.htm).
The second string contain the character [U+00E9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm).

The strings can easily be replaced with str_replace. It is recommended to use the unicode notation (PHP 7+) to avoid misunderstandings.

```
$string = str_replace("e\u{301}","\u{e9}",$string);
```